# pyspark concatonate multiple columns where the column name is in a list

Tags: list, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, concatenation

I am trying to concatonate multiple columns to just one column, but only if the column name is in a list.
so issue = {'a','b','c'} is my list and would need to concatonate it as issue column with ; seperator.

I have tried:
1.

```
df_issue = df.withColumn('issue', concat_ws(';',map_values(custom.({issue}))))
```

Which returns invalid syntax error

2.

```
df_issue = df.withColumn('issue', lit(issue))
```

this just returnd a b c and not their value

Thank you

I have tried:
1.

```
df_issue = df.withColumn('issue', concat_ws(';',map_values(custom.({issue}))))
```

Which returns invalid syntax error

2.

```
df_issue = df.withColumn('issue', lit(issue))
```

this just returnd a b c and not their value

Thank you

Comment: `concat_ws(';', *issue)` -- unpack the list and pass the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `concat_ws`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

columns_to_concat = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df.withColumn('issue', F.concat_ws(';', *columns_to_concat))
```

So, if your input `DataFrame` is:

```bash
+---+---+---+----------+----------+-----+
|  a|  b|  c|     date1|     date2|value|
+---+---+---+----------+----------+-----+
| k1| k2| k3|2022-11-11|2022-11-14|    5|
| k4| k5| k6|2022-11-15|2022-11-19|    5|
| k7| k8| k9|2022-11-15|2022-11-19|    5|
+---+---+---+----------+----------+-----+
```

The previous code will produce:

```bash
+---+---+---+----------+----------+-----+--------+
|  a|  b|  c|     date1|     date2|value|   issue|
+---+---+---+----------+----------+-----+--------+
| k1| k2| k3|2022-11-11|2022-11-14|    5|k1;k2;k3|
| k4| k5| k6|2022-11-15|2022-11-19|    5|k4;k5;k6|
| k7| k8| k9|2022-11-15|2022-11-19|    5|k7;k8;k9|
+---+---+---+----------+----------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much :D 
I have another issue now with the list I am reading it from a sharepoint list column and it looks like this now : "'a','b','c'" do you know how can i remove the " sign ? 
Thank you

Comment: You have to convert it to an actual list, so probably something like: `column_string[1:-1].replace("'", "").split(',')`, where `column_string` is `"'a','b','c'"`

Comment: everything works amazing thank you soo much

Comment: Could you please mark this as solution :)